# Create generic property in interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create an interface with a method GetId(). Depending on the subitems, it could either be an int, string or something else. This is why I tried with return type object (but then I can't specify the type in the subitems) and wanted to try with generics.

How can I do this?

What I already have:

```
public interface INode : IEquatable<INode>
{
   object GetId();
}

public class PersonNode : INode
{
   object GetId(); //can be int, string or something else
}

public class WorkItemNode : INode
{
   int GetId(); //is always int
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at any of the `Related` Links posted on the right of this page..??

Comment: Please explain how the id of a PersonNode can be int, string or somethign else.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes. But it didn't reveal me the solution I got from Jeppe Stig Nielsen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either change `INode` interface to a generic type `interface INode<out T>` as suggested by other answers.

Or if you don't want that, implement your non-generic interface explicitly and supply a type-safe public method as well:

```
public class WorkItemNode : INode
{
    public int GetId() //is always int
    {
        ...
        // return the int
    }

    object INode.GetId()  //explicit implementation
    {
        return GetId();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The second way did it. Thank you very much for this great hint!

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there, just define your interface using `INode<T>`

```
public interface INode<T> : IEquatable<INode<T>>
{
    T GetId();
}

public class PersonNode : INode<string>
{
    public bool Equals(INode<string> other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetId()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class WorkItemNode : INode<int>
{
    public int GetId()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Equals(INode<int> other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could *even* use an `object` with the interface

```
public class OtherItemNode : INode<object>
{
    public bool Equals(INode<object> other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public object GetId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
public interface INode<T> : IEquatable<INode<T>>
{
   T GetId();
}
```

BTW: GetId() is a Method.

a Property would look like this:

```
public interface INode<T> : IEquatable<INode<T>>
{
    T Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Ups, I unintentionally wrote property but coded a method ;)

Comment: And of course a property with only a `get` accessor, no `set`, can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Could your `INode` interface actually be `INode<T>` where T is int, string, whatever?
Then your property can be of type T.

If you need inheritance then you have `INode<T>` and `INode` interfaces where `INode<T>` has the type-specific stuff and `INode` has the non-type-specific stuff (and the object-based property or method for Id retrieval)

Answer (score 0):

He![re is solution for this case Use default int type where you need else use PersonNode T as  generic type and WorkItemNode use int instead of T as default generic type declarations for classes